# How to recycle existing id_rsa private and public key pair in generating a new pem/ppk file?

Tags: ssh

Bill's local machine have existing files:

- `/home/bill/.ssh/id_rsa`
- `/home/bill/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Bill also has a server he wants to connect into.

Is it possible to use the above mentioned key pairs in creating Bill's `bill.pem` key file?

The `bill.pem` key file will be used to connect to Bill's server.

Is this possible? If so, how to recycle those existing key pair in generating a new pem/ppk file?

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: @RalfFriedl I don't know if your question is a legit one or a trolling one but I intendedly wrote the post in a story-style way. I figured out the answer just now though.

Comment: You are allowed to post an answer to your own question, then it's there for others to read.

Answer (score 1):

The .pem/.ppk files are also private key files. In the local machine you simply just have to copy the existing private key file into a .pem file like so:

```bsh
cp /home/bill/.ssh/id_rsa /path/to/intended/bill.pem
```

However, for the `bill.pem` still won't work immediately. The contents of the public key file `/home/bill/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` must be appended first to the server's `authorized_keys` file to make the `bill.pem` work.

Let's say on the server, Bill copied the public key file to

```
/home/bgates/downloads/id_rsa.pub
```

The public key can be appended by doing like so:

```bsh
cat /home/bgates/downloads/id_rsa.pub >> /home/bgates/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Once that's done, Bill can then use the .pem file to access the server like so:

```bsh
ssh -i /path/to/intended/bill.pem bgates@example.com
```